# How to retrieve a drop down list in itemtemplate column of a placeholder inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a Repeater control and i have a Placeholder control and i have added a drop down list into the itemtemplate column of placeholder dynamically.

in Repeater item data bound---

```
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.Attributes.Add("ID", "optionselect");
                ddl.Style.Add("width", "auto");
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Add to store", "store"));
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("add to cart", "cart"));
```

//I want to retrieve the drop down list selected value

```
            var options = new List<OptionsData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < rptOptions.Items.Count; i++)
            {
        //var ddllist = (DropDownList)rptOptions.Items[i].FindControl("optionselect");
```

I am getting object reference not set to an instance of object.. on above line..
Please help....

Thanks.

Comment: You need to assign the `ID`poperty. You also should tell us where you're trying to find the dropdown. Are you recreating it on every postback with the same ID as before?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("ID", "optionselect");
```

with

```
ddl.ID = "optionselect";
```

Property `ID` of a server-side control is not connected anyhow to the collection of client-side attributes of this control.